# Agregar varias imagenes desde formulario - FOR

Tags: php, wordpress

Estoy intentando agregar varias imágenes desde un formulario. 
Se cargan desde $file. Estoy cometiendo un error con el for y no puedo detectarlo.Solo me carga 1 sola imagen de la galeria y la destacada indicada por set_post_thumbnail.
Para rápida comprension indique con comentarios el fragmento con problemas. Gracias!!

```
add_filter('quform_post_process_2', function (array $result, Quform_Form $form) {
$post = array(
    'post_title' => $title,
    'post_content' => $content,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
 'post_category' => array(43)
 );
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$postId = wp_insert_post($post);
$attachmentIds = array();
foreach($files as $file) {
$attachId = my_add_file_attachment($file);
$attachmentIds[] = $attachId;
    }
$file = $form->getValue('quform_2_48');
if (isset($file[0])) {
$attachId = my_add_file_attachment($file[0], $postId);
set_post_thumbnail($postId, $attachId); 
  }


 //Aqui tengo que hacer el bucle

   if (isset($file[1])) {
    $attachId = my_add_file_attachment($file[1], $postId);
   add_post_meta($postId, '_product_image_gallery', $attachId);   
   }


//fin bucle


return $result;
 }, 10, 2);



function my_add_file_attachment($file, $parentPostId = 0){
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php';
$filename = $file['name'];
$path = $file['path'];
$wpFiletype = wp_check_filetype($filename);
$attachment = array(
    'guid' => $file['url'],
    'post_mime_type' => $wpFiletype['type'],
    'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', $filename),
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'inherit'
);
$attachId = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $path, $parentPostId);
$attachData = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attachId, $path);
wp_update_attachment_metadata($attachId, $attachData);
return $attachId;
  }
```

La estructura de la tabla '_product_image_gallery' es 15,58,58
Lo intente con el siguiente codigo sin resultados.

```
 $fileCount = count($file);
 for ($i=1; $i < $fileCount; ++$i) {
 $tain = my_add_file_attachment($file[$i], $postId);}    
 add_post_meta($postId, '_product_image_gallery', implode(',', 
 array_keys($tain)));
```

Comment: Inicializa `$tain` antes del ciclo, creo que debe ser array: `$tain = [];`. Dentro del ciclo agrega cada nuevo elemento en lugar de sobreescribir la variable: `$tain[] = my_add_file_attachment($file[$i], $postId);`

Comment: hola @Triby lo intente pero no funciono, actualice mi codigo a como funciona cuando agrego una sola foto en la galeria por si ayuda..muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

En cada iteración del cciclo estás reescribiendo `$tain` y solo va a conservar el último valor.

```
for ($i=1; $i < $fileCount; ++$i) {
    $tain = my_add_file_attachment($file[$i], $postId);
}
```

Entonces, tienes que crear un array y agregar cada elemento dentro del ciclo:

```
$fileCount = count($file);
// Crear array vacío
$tain = [];
for ($i=1; $i < $fileCount; ++$i) {
    // Agregar cada elemento al array
    $tain[] = my_add_file_attachment($file[$i], $postId);
}    
add_post_meta($postId, '_product_image_gallery', implode(',', array_keys($tain)));
```

Comment: gracias @Triby pero me arrojo  Trying to access array offset on value of type bool en este: `if ( $attachment_ids && has_post_thumbnail() ) {
 foreach ( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) {
  $full_size_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'full' );
  $thumbnail       = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $thumbnail_size );
  $attributes      = array(
       'data-src'                => $full_size_image[0], 'data-large_image'        => $full_size_image[0],
   'data-large_image_width'  => $full_size_image[1],
   'data-large_image_height' => $full_size_image[2],`

Comment: Ese código no está en la pregunta :-(

Comment: correcto.. yo estoy armando un complemento y lo relaciona con woocommerce Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in woocommerce/single-product/product-thumbnails.php

Comment: El problema no parece relacionado a tu pregunta original, creo que deberías crear una nueva pregunta.

Comment: Decis que este código hace que no pueda crear un for por esto?

Comment: No, lo que digo es que es un problema diferente al que planteaste en esta pregunta.

Comment: Lo solucione asi, no es la mejor forma pero funciono:    
     ` if (isset($file[1])) {
        $attachId1 = my_add_file_attachment($file[1], $postId).',';
    } ;
    
     if (isset($file[2])) {
        $attachId2 = my_add_file_attachment($file[2], $postId).',';
     }
....
    $attach_total= $attachId1.$attachId2.$attachId3.$attachId4.$attachId5.$attachId6;
    $attach_totales=rtrim($attach_total,',');
add_post_meta($postId, '_product_image_gallery', $attach_totales);`

Comment: Es difícil apreciarlo así. :-D Pero me alegra que pudiste solucionarlo.